# Any utility which can print out map quickly

Tags: java

I am wondering any utility to print out map quickly for debugging purpose.

Comment: You could use an iterator and for loop to print out the members in 2 lines.

Comment: public class Test {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    java.util.Map<Object, Object> m = new java.util.HashMap<Object, Object>();
    m.put(1, 2); 
    m.put(3, 4); 
    System.err.println(""+m);
  }
}

Answer (score 13):

You can just print the `toString()` of a `Map` to get a 1-line version of the map, divided up in to key/value entries. If that isn't readable enough, you could do your own looping to print or use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) to do this:

```
System.out.println(Joiner.on('\n').withKeyValueSeparator(" -> ").join(map));
```

That'll give you output of the form

```
key1 -> value1
key2 -> value2
...
```

Answer (score 8):

I guess, the .toString() method of implementing class (HashMap or TreeMap for ex.) will do what you want.

Comment: Example output from HashMap.toString: `{key1=value1, key2=value2}`. That's well enough for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 5):

Consider: [MapUtils (Commons Collection 4.2 API)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.2/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html)

It has two methods: debugPrint & verbosePrint.

Answer (score 5):

```
  org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils.debugPrint(System.out, "Print this", myMap);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(map.get(key));
}
```

or simply:

```
System.out.println(map.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public final class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        map.put("key2", "value2");
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{key2=value2, key1=value1}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that `System.out.println` works very well with a map, as this:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("key1", 1);
map.put("key2", 2);        
System.out.println(map);
```

prints:

```
{key1=1, key2=2}
```

Or you can define an utility method like this:

```
public void printMap(Map<?, ?> map)
{
    for (Entry<?, ?> e : map.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println("Key: " + e.getKey() + ", Value: " + e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `StringUtils.join` (from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html))

e.g.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("abc", "123");
map.put("xyz", "456");

System.out.println(StringUtils.join(map.entrySet().iterator(), "|"));
```

will produce

```
abc=123|xyz=456
```